# A weird condition that implies continuity

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

This is a funny problem I can't get my head around. 
Consider a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(\forall [a,b]\subseteq [0,1])$, $f([a,b])$ contains the inverval with endpoints $f(a),f(b)$ and that for every $y\in \mathbb{R}$, the set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed. Prove that $f$ is  continuous.

My thoughts on this.
Approach 1)Consider a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ and show $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$. This doesn't seem to go far.
Approach 2) Let $J$ be closed. Prove $f^{-1}(J)$ is closed in $[0,1]$.
So I begin with 2) and consider $f^{-1}(J)$. But this doesn't have to be an interval, so I get stuck...

Comment: You can assume that $x_n$ and $f(x_n)$ are both monotonic, since you can always split any given sequence into four sub-sequences that satisfy this condition. Then your intervals $[x_n,x]$ and $[f(x_n),f(x)]$ form two nested sequences. Assume that $f(x_n)\to y\neq f(x)$. Then, since $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed, there is a $z\in f^{-1}(y)$ that is closest to $x$ and supposedly inside the intervals $[x_n,x]$. Pick $n$ large enough to kick out that $z$ and arrive to a contradiction to show that $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Would have never guessed it was so intricate. Will look into the construction of the four sub-sequences. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have to be, I just followed your first approach and walked around the inconveniences I found along the way. Very likely the second approach is also viable.

Answer (score 1):

The first given condition states that the intermediate value theorem holds true for that function. For continuous functions the intermediate value theorem is valid, however, the converse is in general not true, consider for example the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $0<x\leq1$ and $f(0)=0$. It is easily seen that this function doesn´t satisfy the additional assumption of closedness of the preimages of singletons. You may start by investigation this (or similar examples) to get an idea on what still is satisfied and where continuity fails. With this intuition you probably will be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. In my opinion, math.SE is supposed to help people to help themselves, which means that it is not always necessarily helpful to give them full solutions. This looks like an exercise question to me, hence a full solution just destroys the learning process.